# Compare two csv files and output specific columns in python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I've met some troubles when I'm processing files.

I'm trying to compare these two files:

file 1(p123):

```
Number,Position,Peptide
1,62,dgwgkvttfpsva
2,189,vtikndteddsin
3,157,qqgkastppvkks
3,165,pvkksftpskspa
3,181,kkepvktpspapa
3,293,tkppsmtesslkn
3,30,rgsdpdttwliis
3,31,gsdpdttwliisp
3,526,ppprratpekkpk
4,150,etegiatpkqken
4,194,qsngketenaena
4,312,egrgdntgdqnav
4,328,dfeksdtegsrig
4,347,fgkrnlteesdvw
4,84,nlpkpetneedee
5,25,qnpllytdflssn
```

files 2(n123):

```
Number,Position,Peptide
1,4,None
1,7,mlrtrltncslwr
1,17,lwrpyytsslsrv
1,50,vnkidltvgiykd
1,62,dgwgkvttfpsva
1,63,gwgkvttfpsvak
1,90,lsylpitgskefq
1,126,risfvqtlsgtga
1,130,vqtlsgtgalava
1,192,wieqlktfaynnq
1,218,acchnptgldptk
1,223,ptgldptkeqwek
1,233,wekiidtiyelkm
1,302,gslsvitpatann
1,305,svitpatanngkf
1,400,hgmfyytrfspkq
1,419,nyfvyltgdgrls
2,32,ggkkfptlgawyd
2,47,neyefqtrcpiil
2,63,hrnkhftfachlk
2,88,naassetsspsan
2,97,psannntnppgtp
2,102,ntnppgtpdhihh
....
5,356,pfssmhttatfqi
5,357,fssmhttatfqik
5,359,smhttatfqikqe
5,375,qkienntaglkdg
5,424,qiskentmmkkki
5,452,lhmqectinggnn
```

As you can see, file 1 is subset of file 2. What I aim to do is to find the non-overlapping part and output column 3, the peptide part.

Here's my code:

```
n = open(r'C:\Users\dengziqi\Desktop\n123.csv','r')
p = open(r'C:\Users\dengziqi\Desktop\p123.csv','r')
n1 = csv.reader(n)
p1 = csv.reader(p)
for p2 in p1:    
    for n2 in n1:
        if n2[1]!= p2[1]:
            print n2[2]
```

I've tried my code, but it did not do any selection. It just output the original column.

the expected result：

```
Number,Position,Peptide
1,4,None
1,7,mlrtrltncslwr
1,17,lwrpyytsslsrv
1,50,vnkidltvgiykd
1,63,gwgkvttfpsvak
1,90,lsylpitgskefq
1,126,risfvqtlsgtga
....
2,32,ggkkfptlgawyd
2,47,neyefqtrcpiil
2,63,hrnkhftfachlk
2,88,naassetsspsan
2,97,psannntnppgtp
2,102,ntnppgtpdhihh
2,138,skldfvtddleyh
2,148,eyhlanthpddtn
2,153,nthpddtndkves
2,184,fkqqgvtikndte
2,189,vtikndteddsin
2,210,ddesgpthgndsg
2,228,eeddvhtqmtkny
2,231,dvhtqmtknysdv
.....
```

---

New requirement(20.03.2017)：
Under the same Number, if position in file 2(n123) belong position in file1(p123) ±50, then abandon and output the rest of peptide

for example:
file 1(p123):

```
Number,Position,Peptide
1,62,dgwgkvttfpsva
....
```

files 2(n123):

```
Number,Position,Peptide
1,4,None
1,7,mlrtrltncslwr
1,17,lwrpyytsslsrv
1,50,vnkidltvgiykd
1,62,dgwgkvttfpsva
1,63,gwgkvttfpsvak
1,90,lsylpitgskefq
1,126,risfvqtlsgtga
1,130,vqtlsgtgalava
1,192,wieqlktfaynnq
1,218,acchnptgldptk
1,223,ptgldptkeqwek
1,233,wekiidtiyelkm
1,302,gslsvitpatann
1,305,svitpatanngkf
1,400,hgmfyytrfspkq
1,419,nyfvyltgdgrls
....
```

so after compare, i need to get:

```
Number,Position,Peptide
1,4,None
1,7,mlrtrltncslwr1,126,risfvqtlsgtga
1,130,vqtlsgtgalava
1,192,wieqlktfaynnq
1,218,acchnptgldptk
1,223,ptgldptkeqwek
1,233,wekiidtiyelkm
1,302,gslsvitpatann
1,305,svitpatanngkf
1,400,hgmfyytrfspkq
1,419,nyfvyltgdgrls
```

I've written some code which can make it work, but the problem is the script is takes too much time. I'm wondering how to improve it.
My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

dfn=pd.read_csv('n123.csv')
dfp=pd.read_csv('p123.csv')
collection1 = []
for index, row in dfp.iterrows():
    for index2, row2 in dfn.iterrows(): #iterate two dataframe and return data
        if row2[0]== row[0]:   #to determine if it is under the same Number
            if int(row2[1])in range(int(row[1])-50, int(row[1])+50) : #determine if the position in n123 ∈ [position in p123 ± 50].  
                collection1.append(row2[2]) #collect the correspond peptide 
collection2 = list(set(collection1)) #remove the duplicate peptide

collection3 = dfn.iloc[:,2].tolist()#return all peptide from n123 as list 

collection4 = list(set(collection3) - set(collection2)) #n123 file peptide list minus the collection 3 list = peptide whose position not in range (position in p123 ± 50）
ng = open("purenegativecollectiondata1.txt", "wb")
for ip in collection4:
    ng.write(ip)
    ng.write('\r\n')
ng.close()
```

I can understand my code is very indirect, so i need some help to improve it.

Comment: Can you add few rows of meaningful data from both files along with header row

Comment: Yes, sorry for that.

Comment: Sorry for the chaos, i was new and messed up the format. Now it's clear.

Comment: Your code is wrong because you consume all the `n1` during the first iteration. That means that for the second line of `p1`, the file `n1` has already been read and there are no lines left. You may solve that by re-reading n1 for each line of `p1` --moving the open, or performing a seek, or I-don't-know-what. But that would be awful in terms of performance and I/O.

Comment: @JackyDeng, show how should look the expected result (*non-overlapping part*)

Comment: I've added the expected result. It means if under the same Number, like 1, if Position in file 2 != Position in file1 (like4,7,17....63,90,126, expect 62), then output

Comment: why not compare the whole lines, not just `Position` ?

Comment: Because it's the first step. I'm developing this script so i can compare with different condition, which is base on position.

Comment: That means that the peptide column on file 1 is completely ignored?

Comment: No exactly, Column 1 is the first condition.It should compare under the same Number. If columa1 (Number) match, then compare position, then output peptide.

Comment: But the peptide that is output is from file 2, not file 1. At least, according to your description. You test set is too long to check by hand. I still cannot see when you are using the peptide on the first file.

Comment: (I am assuming that `file 1 is subset of file 2` <- this is true)

Comment: Yes it is , file 1 is subset of file 2. For example, under the Number 1, file1 peptide in position on 62, but there some peptide in posotion 4,7,17...62,63,90,126. Then i need to extract and abandon peptide from position 62 (which are their common part), only output the rest of peptide of file 2.

Comment: Furthermore, i'm gonna set condition, such as: Under the same Number, if position in file 2 belong position in file1 ±25, then abandon and output the rest of peptide.

Answer (score 0):

Use a set to store the intermediate structure of number/position, and query against that. Example (non-complete, just as a basis):

```
...
seen = set()
for n2 in n1:
    seen.add((n2[0], n2[1]))  # ignore peptide column

for p2 in p1:
    if (p2[0], p2[1]) not in seen:
        print "%s,%s,%s" % p2
```

Sidenote: I am not taking into account headers, that you should do yourself. Maybe using `DictReader` and `DictWriter` is a better idea instead.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. But to find the difference is my first step.Then i have to do the conditionally compare, such as : under the same Number, if Position in file2 not ∈ Position in file1 ± 25, then output column[2] in file2   . So if file 1 as a set, i don't know how to add judge sentences.

Comment: @JackyDeng I think that you did not understand my second option. Anyways, I changed it. Maybe now it suits your needs.

Comment: Hi! I found a solution which can solve my question, but the problem is it takes too much time when the file is big. Could you please look at it? I updated it on above.